# Change var value from dropdown in javascript with onchange

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a dropdown list which looks like this:

```
<select id="cityID">
        <option value="mission">Mission</option>
        <option value="bakersfield">Bakersfield</option>
        <option value="knoxville">Knoxville</option>
</select>
```

And my code to get the value is:

```
var select = document.getElementById('cityID');
var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
text.innerHTML = cityID.value;

text.onchange = function(e) {
   text.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
```

The value always chooses the first item. How can I get it to accept  the cityID and change the page,

I'm sure its a formatting or typo or wrong value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using addEventListener also.

```
var select = document.getElementById('cityID');
var textEl = document.getElementById("text")
select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    textEl.innerText = e.target.value;
})
```

Comment: No mater what I use I get this: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=[object%20HTMLParagraphElement]&appid I tried select, text, textEL, cityID, e and all the same basic result?

Comment: I need to insert the value into this line: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + variable from dropdown select + '&appid=' + key)

Comment: Well I added to the code and now the variable is being passed correct, but  while the select box shows the selections and it works, the <script> section is not refreshing on any changes. What ever is the first value is in the list it just stays that.

Answer (score 1):

1. onchange event is trigger from the select element
2. your text variable seems to be an HTML element because you set its innerHTML property
3. a select element has a "value" property so you don't need to get it from the selectedIndex of the options.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('cityID');
var textEl = document.getElementById("text")
text.innerHTML = select.value;

select.onchange = function(e) {
   textEl.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="cityID">
        <option value="mission">Mission</option>
        <option value="bakersfield">Bakersfield</option>
        <option value="knoxville">Knoxville</option>
</select>

<p id="text"></p>
```